# Set optional parameter put the others with a default value at nil

Tags: ruby

I face a weirb problem with optionals parameters in ruby.
This is my code :

```
def foo options={:test => true}
    puts options[:test]
end

foo # => puts true
foo :lol => 42 # => puts nil
```

I can not figure out why the second call puts nil.
Is seems that putting an other parameter set :test to nil.

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because if it is a default parameter, passing a hash parameter will completely overwrite it (ie. it sets `options = {:lol => 42}`), so the `options[:test]` key no longer exists.

To give particular hash keys default values, try:

```
def foo options={}
  options = {:test => true}.merge options
  puts options[:test]
end
```

In this case, we merge a hash with default values for certain keys (`{:test => true}`), with another hash (containing the key=>values in the argument). If a key occurs in both hash objects, the value in the hash passed to the `merge` function will take precedence.